# Change Google Map marker on Jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm trying to change GoogleMap marker icon by clicking div and using jquery. But it doesn't seem to be working, marker icon doesn't change. I assigned a variable that contains image path, but the thing is that if jquery changes it, it stays inside jquery function and is not passed back to global value.
Here is my code:

JS part

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#hurricanes').click(function (e){
iconic=jQuery(this).attr('hurr.png');
    initMap();
});
$('#earthquakes').click(function (e){
iconic=jQuery(this).attr('durr.png');
    initMap();
});    
});


var iconBase = 'img/';
var iconic;
function createMarker(latlng, name, address1, address2, postalCode) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        title: name,
        icon: iconBase + iconic
    });

}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -0.397,
            lng: 10.644
        },
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });
    displayMarkers();
}
```

And HTML buttons:

```
    <div id="hurricanes" class="choices">HURRICANES</div>
    <div id="earthquakes" class="choices">EARTHQUAKES</div>
```

Comment: `iconic=jQuery(this).attr('hurr.png');` what do you think this is doing? guarantee you are mistaken

Comment: I'm trying to change var iconic; by that, it didn't work with simple iconic='durr.png'; either, iconic value doesn't seem to be affected by jquery function at all

Comment: `iconic=jQuery(this).attr('hurr.png');` will get the attribute called `hurr.png` of the clicked element ... so, that will be null/undefined ...so remove that code for a start

Comment: What  are you trying to do when you click the button?  Change all the markers on the map to a different icon?  What does your map code look like, how are you adding the markers to the map?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should reinitialize the map using JavaScript after you changed the marker. Have a look in the API Reference for all the options: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

Although I am not quite sure what you are exactly going to do, you can also remove the markers in specific coordinates and then add the new ones with new marker icons.

Comment: iconic variable stores the path to the marker image, that is used in google maps function that initializes map. I only need some way to change that global variable with jquery so it gets updated in the map function

Comment: Basically global variable doesn't get changed with jquery.

Comment: you're changing the value of "iconic" but the map is already created in your page,isn't it? if yes then you need to call the CreateMarker function again.

Comment: I did that, but iconic value is still unchanged.

Comment: I'm glad you made it. For having a cleaner code you can pass an object to the CreateMarker and set the icon name and other required info in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by reinitializing both functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#hurricanes').click(function (e){
iconic='hurr.png';
    createMarker();
    initMap();
    console.log(iconic);
});
$('#earthquakes').click(function (e){
iconic='durr.png';
    createMarker();
    initMap();
    console.log(iconic);
});


});
```